# Program running from command line but not from executable created by pyinstaller

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have converted my .py program to an exe using pyinstaller. However, when I click the executable it starts with the following error then proceeds to request input. After the input, the exe shuts down with some errors that I cannot see. The program executable runs normally when ran from the command line.Libraries used are matplotlib ,pandas and numpy and I am using x64 windows.

error
'''
c:\users\bless\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:627: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)

''''

Comment: This is just a warning ! and does your program requires any arguments ?

Comment: To help troubleshoot issues, knowing the context is crucial. The platform, software versions, etc. Could you please share versions of the platform (Windows), Python and PyInstaller (and important libraries used), how do you run it successfully with Python, which PyInstaller options you used to create the binary, etc.

Comment: I am using windows x64 system ,matplotlib,matplotlib,and numpy.Python 3.7 and pyinstaller latest version.

Comment: No it does not require any arguments.